# How can I force @AutoConfigureJsonTesters to use HAL format from spring-hateoas?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-hateoas, spring-boot-test

I have a small module that should only contain the resource model of my REST service.  I want to create a test in this module to ensure that the resource model serializes and deserializes appropriate HAL format.

I have a single test and this is the configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureJsonTesters
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var collectionTester: JacksonTester<Resources<Entity>>

 ....
}
```

and a very simple configuration

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
class TestConfig
```

When calling collectionTester.write on a list of Entity (which extends ResourceSupport) I don't get an _embedded field, instead I get

```
{"links":[],"content":[...]}
```

which is not HAL format.

How can I force @AutoConfigureJsonTesters to give me a JacksonTester with an ObjectMapper configured for HAL?

Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get @ AutoConfigureJacksonTesters from shouldn't it be AutoConfigureJsonTesters?

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry, I rewrote by hand instead of copying and pasting, will fix!

Answer (score 0):

The auto-configured `JacksonTester` will use the context’s `ObjectMapper` which won’t have any of the Spring HATEOAS stuff configured on it. You might be better creating a `JacksonTester` yourself and passing it an appropriately configured `ObjectMapper` to use.

I believe Spring HATEOAS has a module that it applies to the `ObjectMapper` to configure it. If you get stuck with that, asking in gitter/spring-projects/spring-data is probably your best bet as Spring HATEOAS is maintained by the Data team due to it being used by Spring Data REST.